# TypeScript import failing in CI environment

Tags: typescript, es6-modules

I am using Preact + TypeScript + Jest + Enzyme to run a set of tests against my application. The tests run fine in my local development environment but they fail when running in the CircleCI environment with the following error:

**error TS2307: Cannot find module '../../src/routes/public/Article' or its corresponding type declarations.**

I have even tried moving the imported module into the same folder as the test file and changed the import to be "./Article" but it still fails with the same error.

It seems like there is an issue importing local modules when running the tests within CircleCI. Any ideas where to start with this?

Answer (score 1):

OK...figured it out. The folder named "public" was showing with a lowercase "p" in Visual Studio but actually had an upper case "P" on the file system and in git. Renaming that with a lowercase fixed it!